# How to convert to tflite 8-bit (or 16-bit) quantized from model with input tensor of variable size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to create a quantized tflite model from a tensorflow graph which has variable size input tensor. To do this I'm using tensorflow 1.14, and cannot switch to a later version. I saw [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29590) that tf-nightly (Feb-2020) supports variable input tensors for tflite. Unfortunately this is not an option for me.

I do not need a variable input tensor for my tflite model. Is there still an option for me?

I tried simply setting the input tensor manually:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_cfg, model_outputs = load_model("my_model.pb", sess)
    img = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('image:0') # This does not work unfortunately
    img = tf.placeholder(name="image", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(1, 257, 257, 3)) # Try manually

    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [img], model_outputs)
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE] # 8-bit quantization
    tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
    open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_quant_model)
```

This gives me a quantized model but one which i cannot use.

I get an error:

```
input->dims->size != 4 (0 != 4)Node number 0 (CONV_2D) failed to prepare
```

which I believe is due to the fact that my manual insertion of the input tensor is not "connected" to the rest of the model.

Comment: May I ask why upgrading to a version that solves the problem is not an option?

Comment: I want to run the network on an embedded system where only 1.14 is available